# Change/swap values one after another in pandas dataframe for selected rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Dataframe:

```
col1 col2
  A    0
  A    1
  A    nan
  B    0
  B    1
  C    and so on...
```

I am trying to change 1 to 0, 0 to 1 and nan stays as such in col2 wherever col1=='A'.

Code so far:

```
df.loc[(df.col1=='A') & (df.col2==0),'col2'] = 2
df.loc[(df.col1=='A') & (df.col2==1),'col2'] = 0
df.loc[(df.col1=='A') & (df.col2==2),'col2'] = 1

# Hope you understand why I am converting 0 to 2 first then to 1.
# Because if I convert all zeroes to 1 then all 1's will be converted to 
# 0 in subsequent conversion.
```

Unique values in col2 are 0,1 and nan.
Is there a correct/better way of doing this?
Also, is there a way to directly swap these numbers instead of assignment operators?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution using [`Series.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.where.html) and [`astype(bool)`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.astype.html) with `~` (NOT operator) and then back to `astype(int)`. Then use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html) with [`boolean indexing`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) to assign back to `DataFrame`:

```
df.loc[df.col1.eq('A'), 'col2'] = df.col2.where(df.col2.isna(),
                                               (~df.col2.astype(bool)).astype(int))
```

[out]

```
  col1  col2
0    A   1.0
1    A   0.0
2    A   NaN
3    B   0.0
4    B   1.0
5    C   NaN
```

Comment: filters for col1=='A' are not present and i don't think isna is applicable for series, is it?

Comment: @Mysterious apologies, I have added filter for switching values where `col1=='A'` only. And yes, `isna` is a method availble for `Series`

Comment: It works, thanks! I have only one question though. If I do len(LHS) in your code and len(RHS) i get different numbers. Shouldn't the length be same in pandas while assigning values. How does pandas make sure that the right positions are used from RHS?

Comment: It's because LHS is filtered (Only includes rows where `col1` is 'A')... RHS is not filtered, it includes every row in the DataFrame. When assigning, pandas will align the index from LHS and RHS to update the values in the DataFrame. So in this example, the values at indices `[0, 1, 2]` will be updated to the new values at indices `[0, 1, 2]` from the RHS

Comment: Ohkay, so just out of curiosity, if i shuffle the RHS, will it still work because the index will not change, only the order of the values will change that is [0, 1, 2] will become [2, 0, 1]?

Comment: Yes exactly. You can try this for yourself by chaining on `.sample(frac=1)` to the RHS. It will randomly shuffle the `Series`, but should still output the same end result

Answer (score 2):

You can also try with [`df.mask()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.mask.html):

```
m=df.col1.eq('A')&df.col2.isna() #condition
df.col2=1-df.col2.mask(m)
print(df)
```

---

```
  col1  col2
0    A   1.0
1    A   0.0
2    A   NaN
3    B   1.0
4    B   0.0
```

Answer (score 1):

> I am trying to change 1 to 0, 0 to 1 and nan stays as such in col2
>   wherever col1=='A'.

use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
df['col2] = np.where(df['col1'] == 'A', np.where(df['col2'] == 1, 0 , np.where(df['col2'].isnull() == True, df['col2'],1)),df['col2'])
```

**Output**

```
  col1  col2
0    A   1.0
1    A   0.0
2    A   NaN
3    B   0.0
4    B   1.0
5    C   0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you can also use your own function in combination with `apply()`.

```
# import pandas
import pandas as pd

# make a sample data
list_of_rows = [
  {'col1': A, 'col2': 1},
  {'col1': A, 'col2': 0},
  {'col1': A, 'col2': None},
  {'col1': B, 'col2': 0},
  {'col1': B, 'col2': 1},
  {'col1': B, 'col2': None},
]

# make a pandas data frame
df = pd.DataFrame(list_of_rows)

# define a function
def change_values(row):
    if row['col2'] == 0:
        return 1
    if row['col2'] == 1:
        return 0
    return row['col2']

# apply function to dataframe
df['col2'] = df.apply(lambda row: change_values(row), axis=1)
```